# Plots of different rows on the same graph

Tags: r, plot

I found an interesting thread about plotting but I'm not happy with the answer. I would like to plot different amount of rows on the same graph. Just giving me the possibility to add as much rows as I want to.

I'd like to use `glopts` library but I am open for any other. First of all I want to plot those rows into pdf file. The script which I want to modify is:

```
which_rows <- c(12,156,4432) ## I want to choose which row I want to plot

pdf(file='Plots'.pdf)

x <- 1:(ncol(data_plot)-1) ## Can it be changed to use the name of the columns instead of pure numbers ?

for(i in which_rows){
 ## create new pdf page BUT I WANT TO PLOT IT ON THE SAME GRAPH!
  plot(x=x,y=data_plot[i,-1],type='b',main=data_plot[i,1],xlab='columns',ylab='Intensity')
}

# closing pdf
dev.off()
```

Can you help me to modify this script to print just all of the rows which I decide on the same graph ? Would be great if you show me how I can jsut add new page in this pdf file using the other set of rows like `which_rows2`.

Of course each plot should has diffent colour or something.

Edit:

[image: Just one of the plots from my data. I want different colours and plots on the same graph]

Comment: Please post an example graph. I can't tell whether you want a grid of graphs, a multipage output, or what.

Comment: Added, would like to change the number of columns from my data to the name of them.

Answer (score 2):

use `points()`to add points to the existing plot